# Dynamic allocation of 2D char array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, realloc

i know its a bad idea to use realloc each time you add an item but im just trying to learn about memory management here.Why is this program crashing ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
char str[] = "some text";
char **stringList = (char**) malloc( sizeof(char*));

for (int n=0;n<15;n++){
stringList[n] = (char*) malloc( (strlen(str)+1) );
strcpy(stringList[n], str);
stringList=realloc(stringList, (n+2) * sizeof(char*));
n++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is [no need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#605858) to cast the result of a call to `malloc()`.

Comment: You've written `n++` inside your loop. This means `n` will increase by 2 with every loop iteration. Is this a mistake?

Comment: It's fine to realloc each time

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson it certainly is a mistake, as the first `realloc` allocates `2` rows, and then `stringlist[2] = ` writes out of bounds

Comment: The normal structure of code like this is to do the `realloc()` **before** you put something into the new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's crashing is because you're incrementing `n` twice. You have `n++` in the `for()` header, and then again at the bottom of the loop.

The first time through the loop everything works fine. Your initial allocation of the array has 1 element, you've set `n = 0`, so assigning to `stringList[n]` is fine.

Then you do `realloc(stringList, (n+2)*sizeof(char*))`. Now the array has 2 elements.

`n++` at the bottom of the loop sets `n = 1`, and `n++` in the `for()` header sets `n = 2`.

Then you go back into the loop body, and try to assign to `stringList[n]`. This is outside the array bounds, because `n = 2` and the only valid indexes are `stringList[0]` and `stringList[1]`.

This repeats every further time through the loop, always assigning to the array element just past the end. Accessing outside the bounds of an array causes undefined behavior, and you're getting a crash as a result.

Get rid of the `n++` at the bottom of the loop and you should be OK.

Comment: thanks, i read the code like 10 times but didn't notice the n++, i guess i need some sleep

Comment: How did you miss it when you stepped through the program in the debugger, though? You did try using a debugger before posting here, didn't you?